# web.configuration file in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net

Hello i want to transfer my web application to the remote server, this is my local web.config file, can someone pls help me with this? I am using godaddy.I know i have to use the remove .. but i don't know how to do it using visual studio 2010. I am also confuse with the `add name="applicationservices"`. in visual studio 2005 its `<add name="LocalSqlServer"`
Please i need help and clarification

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should clear you mind and think about a question before asking it. What you have posted is very difficult to understand.

Comment: Awww man, this question is going to get messy. He's using SQL Express attached database, which doesn't work in non-sql express, so it wont work on go-daddy.

Answer (score 2):

1: You need to upload your database to your server.

2: Use godaddy's functionality to attach that database to their SqlServer.

3: Adjust your connectionstring to point to the DB on godaddy's server. You will have to ask them for the format.

4: Adjust your web.config.

[Check if this helps:](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNET_Membership_1.aspx)